# i want fwrite then fread file , but it not run

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqp5d.png)

sorry , my eng very bad
ok , i want fwrite then fread file , but i can't do it ,
can you help me

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

    int main(){
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("trungbinh","wb");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
    }
    float a,b,c;
    printf("Nhap 3 so a b c : ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    scanf("%f",&b);
    scanf("%f",&c);
    float x= (a+b+c)/3;
    printf("Trung binh con cua 3 so la %.3f",x);
    fwrite(&x,sizeof(float),1,f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: you can see my images in the head

Comment: sorry this is fist time i use stackoverflow

Comment: you can see image in head post , this have all you need to help me

Comment: Your question seems to depend on two programs, but you posted only one into the question. The other program is only visible as an image. Please post the code of both programs into the question. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: Please update question and explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second program `vidu2.exe` (the one which has not been posted into the question, but is only visible in the image), the line

```
if(f=NULL){
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
if(f==NULL){
```

This is causing your `fread` function call to fail.